# Binding on observableArray created from another observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I have an object returned from a ajax call and from this object I want to do some calculations on it, depending on inputs from the user. Inputs being a number input and checkbox to include another figure in the calculation or not.

My JS is:

```
var viewModel = function() 
{
        var self = this;
    self.currentVal = ko.observable(2);
    self.includeTax = ko.observable(false);
    self.sales = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.computedSales = ko.observableArray([]);

self.sales([
    {"ProductID": "10121a", "Cost": 110, "Quantity": 6, "X": 9034.25, "Other": 23, "Date": 2017-05-5}, 
    {"ProductID": "10122b", "Cost": 10, "Quantity": 18, "X": 152.99, "Other": 20, "Date": 2017-05-3},
    {"ProductID": "10123c", "Cost": 1000, "Quantity": 2, "X": 99.50, "Other": 5, "Date": 2017-05-1}]);

self.computeSales = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.sales(), function (item) {
    self.computedSales().push({
        "ProductID": item.ProductID, 
      "Total": item.Cost * item.Quantity,
      // "Total" is needed for the Calc value, is there a way to re-use the Total without having to duplicate it below?:
      // "Calc": item.Cost * item.Quantity * (self.currentVal / 100)
      "Calc": self.includeTax() == true ? (item.Cost * item.Quantity * (2 / 100) * .5) : (item.Cost * item.Quantity * 2 / 100)
      });

      //alert(self.computedSales()[self.computedSales().length -1].Total);
  });
  // self.currentVal not correct:
  //alert(self.currentVal);
};
self.computeSales();
};

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

The `Calc` column does not change when I tick the checkbox nor change the value in the input - what am I doing wrong?

My main aim was to find a way to re-use some of the properties such as Total, instead of having to duplicate `item.Cost * item.Quantity`, but I guess this is another separate question.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/or6w9or1/9/)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be easier if your sales objects were actually strongly typed objects that you could attach a computed to. Firstly, you should create an object for your sales:

```
var sale = function(item) {
    var thisSale = this;
    thisSale.productId = ko.observable(item.ProductID);
    thisSale.cost = ko.observable(item.Cost);
    thisSale.quantity = ko.observable(item.Quantity);
    //etc with all properties needed.
    thisSale.calc = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return self.includeTax() == true ? (thisSale.Cost * thisSale.Quantity * (2 / 100) * .5) : (thisSale.Cost * thisSale.Quantity * 2 / 100)
    });
}
```

Then create these objects with your data:

```
self.computeSales = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.sales(), function (item) {
        self.computedSales().push({
            new sale(item);
        });
    });
};
```

A computed value will update whenever an observable that it references updates so by making the calc a computed value you should be able to have it updated when the checkbox is altered. Apologies if this isn't very clear and I haven't tested this code at all so you may need to tweak it but the general principle should be there!